# Exporting Powershell CMDlets from DLLs loaded by [Reflection.Assembly]::Load()

Tags: powershell, dll, .net-assembly, gac, powershell-cmdlet

I have an environment where files cannot be written to disk, and so I usually load DLLs from memory in the GAC.

While loading is not a problem, exposing the DLL Commandlets is.
The Assembly is loaded:

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname

FullName
--------
AudioDeviceCmdlets, Version=3.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

fl *

```
CodeBase            : file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
FullName            : AudioDeviceCmdlets, Version=3.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
EntryPoint          :
DefinedTypes        : {CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolume, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeCallback, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeChannel, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeChannels...}
Evidence            : {<System.Security.Policy.Url version="1">
                      <Url>file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll</Url>
                      </System.Security.Policy.Url>
                      , <System.Security.Policy.Zone version="1">
                      <Zone>MyComputer</Zone>
                      </System.Security.Policy.Zone>
                      }
PermissionSet       : {}
SecurityRuleSet     : Level2
ManifestModule      : AudioDeviceCmdlets.dll
ReflectionOnly      : False
Location            :
ImageRuntimeVersion : v4.0.30319
GlobalAssemblyCache : False
HostContext         : 0
IsDynamic           : False
EscapedCodeBase     : file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
ExportedTypes       : {CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolume, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeChannel, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeChannels, CoreAudioApi.AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate...}
IsFullyTrusted      : True
CustomAttributes    : {[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute((Int32)8)], [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute(WrapNonExceptionThrows = True)],
                      [System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute((System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute+DebuggingModes)2)], [System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("AudioDeviceCmdlets")]...}
Modules             : {<unknown>}
```

..but the CMDLets are not exported.. of course I'm surely missing something.

The same DLL, loaded in the 'regular' way:

```
load-module AudioDeviceCmdlets.dll
```

correctly exports several CmdLets, like ***Get-AudioDevice*** and ***Set-AudioDevice***.

Any hint on what steps I'm missing to expose the Cmdlets in the dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it seems very rude, ***(and I'm still open to better answers!)*** 
this works:

1) Select the first instance of the available Assembly (as there could be more than one, or be more specific in finding the one you want to load):

```
$Assembly=([System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()|? FullName -Match "AudioDeviceCmdlets")[0]
```

2) Import the assembly using Import-Module but, instead of specifying the dll to load, reference the Assembly directly. **Without a manifest, it will default to exporting all the variables and all the functions therein**

```
Import-Module -Assembly $Assembly
```

Voila, now the Commandlets are correctly exported! :)

Comment: No, this is the right way if you need to do it in-memory (updated my answer as well, `Relection.Load()` returns the `Assembly` object, no need to search for it again) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Import-Module -Assembly`:

```
$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($UncompressedFileBytes)    
Import-Module -Assembly $assembly
```

Alternatively, create a module manifest that loads the assembly and then import that:

```
New-ModuleManifest .\AudioDeviceCmdlets.psd1 -RequiredAssemblies AudioDeviceCmdlets
Import-Module .\AudioDeviceCmdlets.psd1
```

Comment: ..but I can't write locally the psd1 manifest... could I load it from, say, a scriptblock?

Comment: The bare minimum manifest I have is: @{
RootModule = 'AudioDeviceCmdlets.dll'
ModuleVersion = '3.0.0.4'
GUID = '7156b1c0-8e86-4d19-8df1-058c15629f36'
Author = 'Francois Gendron <fg@frgn.ca>'
PowerShellVersion = '3.0'
FunctionsToExport = '*'
CmdletsToExport = '*'
VariablesToExport = '*'
AliasesToExport = '*'
}
but so far I've been succesful loading it just from file. No way of loading it from a variable/from memory?